# How to change space value between grid and yAxis in Highcharts line chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a chart with only 1 value, and I d'like to know how i can reduce space between my Y axis and lines of the grid ?
Thanks.
Here a screenshot : [image: Chart]

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?

Comment: @KacperMadej Not really easy to do, because there's a lot of dynamic data. I'm gonna try nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is the `offset` attribute of the `yAxis`. I would suggest you to try something like:

```
yAxis: {
  /*
  ...
  */,
  offset: -30
},
```

See [this documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset) for more details.